# How can I make highlighting commands in .vimrc take effect immediately with Vim 7.4?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype

I have several `highlight` commands in my `.vimrc` file. In Vim 7.3, these took effect immediately after Vim had started. After updating to Vim 7.4, this is not the case anymore. Vim uses its default highlighting initially. When I load `.vimrc` a second time by executing `source ~/.vimrc`, highlighting works as I want.

You should be able to reproduce this problem using the following steps:

1. Make a copy of your `.vimrc` file.
2. Replace `~/.vimrc` with a file that contains just the line `highlight Type ctermfg=28 cterm=bold`.
3. Run `vim dummy.c` in a 256 color terminal (for example GNOME Terminal).
4. Type `int` into the buffer. The `int` should appear in regular font and be colored light green, which is not what I want.
5. Enter `:source ~/.vimrc`. Now the `int` should appear in bold font and be colored dark green.

According to the article [*How to control/configure vim colors*](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax), it should be okay to just put the `highlight` commands into `.vimrc`. The article says that you should put `syntax enable` after the `highlight` commands, but this did not make any difference.

My first fix was to prepend each `highlight` command in `.vimrc` with `autocmd VimEnter *`. This worked for some file types, but not for others (C files are an example).

What is the reason for this behavior? How can I have the `highlight` commands executed when Vim is started such that they take effect for all buffers during the whole Vim session?

Comment: sounds like issue [542](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/542)

Comment: Yes, when adding `set compatible` at the beginning of `.vimrc`, syntax highlighting works as expected. So this really seems to be this bug in action.

Comment: I have preceded the `highlight` commands with `autocmd ColorScheme *`, which was proposed as a workaround in the bug report. It *still* does not work. ☹

Comment: I am now writing my own color scheme, which apparently also works around this bug.

Comment: Christian, can you just write your comment as an answer? After all, this is the right answer to my problem. Or is there any other approach for dealing with questions that actually reveal bugs?

Comment: it's no answer, but will do

Comment: place `hi` after `colo`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19910/9598

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is no definite answer and your problem sounds like issue [542](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/542). Apparently you can work around it, by writing your own basic colorscheme, instead of writing those `hi ...` statements directly into your .vimrc.

Comment: I think it is because of this Vim issue; so your reponse really seems to be the correct answer to my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you shouldn't put your custom highlights in your vimrc but in customs syntax files.

These files should be located in `~/.vim/after/syntax/filetype.vim` where `filetype` is the expected filetype. If you are mostly satisfied with a syntax file but would like to add a few command you can follow these steps (taken from [`:h mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile%2Dadd)):

> 1. Create a directory in there called "after/syntax".  For Unix:
>
>    ```
>     mkdir ~/.vim/after
>     mkdir ~/.vim/after/syntax
>    ```
> 2. Write a Vim script that contains the commands you want to use.  For
>    example, to change the colors for the C syntax:
>
>    ```
>     highlight cComment ctermfg=Green guifg=Green
>    ```
> 3. Write that file in the "after/syntax" directory.  Use the name of the
>    syntax, with ".vim" added.  For our C syntax:

> ```
>     :w ~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim
> ```
>
> That's it.  The next time you edit a C file the Comment color will be
> different.  You don't even have to restart Vim.

[`:h mysyntaxfile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile) is a good place to get information about how to right your own syntax files. Also [Learn Vimscript The Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html) has several chapters on this topic.

Comment: What if I want to change the highlighting for all file types. For example, I want the color of comments to be dark blue, no matter what the file type is.

Comment: I tried out more or less the approach you suggested. I added a file `.vimrc/highlighting.vim`, created a directory `.vimrc/syntax/after` and added several symbolic links of the form *filetype*`.vim` that point to `.vimrc/highlighting.vim` to this directory. Syntax highlighting still does not work.

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch Yup as my post and the doc says the directory should be `~/.vim/after/syntax` not `~/.vimrc`

Comment: That’s correct. However, this was only a typo in my comment. Actually, I worked in the directory `.vim` and syntax highlighting did not work, probably because of this bug 542.

Comment: nope! not working.

Comment: Files inside `syntax` should be named as the filetype they should be applied to, i.e. a syntax file for C should be named `c.vim`. There's no `highlighting` filetype, that's why `~/.vim/after/syntax/highlighting.vim` doesn't work. If you want to reuse highlights defined in one filetype in another filetype you can source the former: `so ~/.vim/after/syntax/myotherfile.vim`. As statox pointed out it's all explained in `:h mysyntaxfile`

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch Did you ever figure out how to set same highlighting for all file types?

Comment: I wrote my own color scheme, which I load with the `colorscheme` command. See `:help colorscheme`.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I had this problem with MacVim (8.1.950 (155)). Placing the highlight statement after `colorscheme` in .vimrc fixed it for me. E.g.:

```
highlight SpellCap guisp=Yellow
...
colorscheme evening
```

->

```
colorscheme evening
...
highlight SpellCap guisp=Yellow
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on MacVim 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Halil Özgür's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19910/41036), putting the `highlight` statement after a `set background=dark` command that I had in my vimrc file worked for me.

macOS, VIM 8.2

EDIT Just found this from the help files:

```
The ":syntax enable" command will keep your current color settings.  This
allows using ":highlight" commands to set your preferred colors before or
after using this command.  If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the
defaults, use: >
    :syntax on
```

If you were using `syntax on`, switching to `syntax enable` might help.