# vim 8.0 not honoring custom colors

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I updated from 7.4 to 8.0 last night and vim stopped honoring the `highlight` commands in my `.vimrc` file.

Minimal complete example: with a `.vimrc` that contains only the following

```
" a comment
sy enable
hi Comment ctermfg=darkCyan
```

the comment on line 1 is still blue when I open that file. (However when I re-source it via `:so %` it becomes cyan, so the file itself works).

I also tried defining a user colorscheme (and even naming it `colors/default.vim`) but it does not work any better.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10035/860),
which refers to [issue #542](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/542) of Vim, where
Bram suggest to use `ColorScheme` auto-command as the right way to customize
colors:

```
augroup customhighlight
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi Comment ctermfg=darkCyan
augroup end
```

Alternatively, refer to answers of that previous question for a different approach that
involves making small custom colorscheme to tweak colors.

These two approaches seem to be the only reliable solutions. On multiple occasions Vim will drop all colors and reload colorscheme from the disk using [`g:colors_name`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#g:colors_name) variable to pick the file. This wipes any customizations made in `vimrc` unless they were in an auto-command or in the color scheme. Putting `:hi` commands in `vimrc` might make configuration dependent on the order of lines (for example, `set background=dark` command can drop all color customizations that precede it).

Comment: If so, that'd be better edited into the question (which also has the advantage of not advertising my embarrassing reading comprehension fail). ;)