# Vim 8.1 Globally custom highlight colors

Tags: vimrc, linux-ubuntu

#### Problem

I'm finally getting around to upgrading from Vim 7.4 to Vim 8.1, but my global custom 
highlight colors have stopped working.

*I am aware similar questions ([such as this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12796/vim-8-0-not-honoring-custom-colors)) have been asked, but these all seem to be related to the closed [Issue #542](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/542), and none of the solutions there seem to work for me.*

#### Version Info

8.1 from the [jonathonf/vim](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim-daily) ppa repository on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug 22 2018 11:42:48)
Included patches: 1-346
Modified by jonathonf.fernyhough@york.ac.uk
```

[Full `--version` text](https://pastebin.com/raw/HD8c6Ynr) (Pastebin link)
I also tried [Vim 8.0](https://pastebin.com/raw/EpT0yzkw) from Ubuntu 18.04's `vim` package

#### Minimum steps to reproduce

Create the following `.vimrc` file:

```
echo "Read the correct vimrc"
hi Comment ctermfg=green cterm=none
```

Edit any file with comments; "Read the correct vimrc" is displayed, but the comment color is not green.

Additionally, sometimes I can see the color change a few milliseconds after the file is opened, suggesting something may indeed be overriding my settings.

Running `:hi Comment ...` from within vim works as expected.

Running `vim` with/without `-u .vimrc` does not make a difference.

#### Other things I've tried

I've tried using the `autocmd` suggestion from the above linked answer, to no avail. In short, that looks something like this:

```
augroup customhighlight
        autocmd!
        autocmd ColorScheme * hi Comment ctermfg=green
augroup end
```

---

I then went down the rabbit hole of vimrc defaults:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

Unfortunately, unless I missed something, there doesn't appear to be anything in the default/Debian vim defaults that would override a user `.vimrc`, and, indeed, that would be silly.

---

I have *not* gone down the route of implementing custom color schemes, which was another suggestion. Reason being, I work with *a lot* of different filetypes on a regular basis, and there has always been a way to globally customize colors, so I'm hoping there's a solution.

---

`:verbose hi Comment` reports:

```
Comment        xxx term=bold ctermfg=14 guifg=#80a0ff
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

`:colorscheme` reports `default`

#### Summary

What is the best practice to set global syntax highlight color preferences in Vim 8.x?

Comment: Could a colorscheme be overriding it? What color is Comment set to? What about `verbose hi Comment` ?

Comment: From my reading of the Vim help, either your direct setting of the Comment highlight, if no colorscheme was set, or your ColorScheme autocommand, if a colorscheme was set, should have worked. If we find it's not working, we can submit a bug report. Before doing that, though, try executing this command: `:verbose hi Comment`. That should tell you where the Comment highlighting was last set. You might also execute `:au ColorScheme` to see if there are any other ColorScheme autocommands that might be overriding yours.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble and @garyjohn I've edited the question with that information. Looks otherwise normal to me, except something is (re)setting the highlight colors after .vimrc. There is no autocommand reported by `:au ColorScheme`.

Comment: It looks like `syntax on` could be the culprit. Is your custom highlight before or after that line in your vimrc ?

Comment: Since the Comment highlight was last set in syncolor.vim, I looked at that file and also read ":help syncolor". There it suggests creating a file ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim and uses as an example setting the Comment highlight. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: `syntax on` didn't seem to make a difference if it was before, after, or not included whatsoever. Similarly with `syntax enable`.

However, the `syncolor.vim` approach *does* work. I checked the `syncolor` documentation for 7.2 and it hasn't changed much. I'd be more willing to accept I've been doing it wrong for the past twenty-ish years if setting right in `.vimrc` didn't work so well up until 8.0!

Thanks @garyjohn . Although I no longer have a "one file" portable Vim configuration, at least it works. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what changed between Vim 7.4 and 8.1 that caused this change in behavior, but the output of `:verbose hi Comment` that you posted provided a clue to a solution. `:help syncolor` suggests overriding the default highlighting colors by creating a file named `~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim` (`~\vimfiles\after\syntax\syncolor.vim` on Windows) and putting in that file highlight commands like the following.

```
if &background == "light"
    highlight Comment ctermfg=darkgreen guifg=darkgreen
else
    highlight Comment ctermfg=green guifg=green
endif
```