# Any reason why one should avoid to force the linking of highlight groups in syntax files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

### tl;dr

Are there any undesirable side-effects connected to the use of `:highlight! default link {from-group} {to-group}` as compared to `:highlight default …` that I should be aware of when editing/creating a syntax file?

### *Director's cut*

In the context of trying to understand how syntax highlighting works in Vim, I tend to have opened the syntax file for a given language and a sample of code written in that language, so that I can see the effects on the latter of editing the former simply by `sourcing` my `.vimrc`.

However, I have seen that some type of edit is not reflected unless I open the file in another session of Vim.

For example, I changed this line in `sed.vim`

```
hi def link sedError       Error
```

to this

```
hi def link sedError       NONE
```

and then `source`d my `.vimrc` in a flawed `file.sed` I had open beside; I saw the `Error` highlight disappear. This is what I expected. Then I restored the line above as it was, sourced my `.vimrc` again, but the color did not come back.

Based on what I read in `:h :hi-link`, it seems I could simply add `!` to the `hi`light command; I have tried, and it works.

However, I have observed that only `fortran.vim` and `chicken.vim` make links like this

```
hi! def link fortranTypeR       fortranType
```

whereas all other syntax files use something like this (from `cpp.vim`)

```
hi def link cppBoolean      Boolean
```

therefore I started suspecting that there could be something not advisable in using `hi!` instead of `hi` in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason not all syntax scripts use `!` when linking highlight definitions is that users could have a preferred way to show certain things in certain ways, and declare these on their `.vimrc`. Syntax scripts are loaded when a `FileType` event occurs, i.e. after the `.vimrc` file is sourced, so if the syntax script uses `hi! link` it doesn't matter that the user had something like `hi! def link cppBoolean Function`, the former will overwrite the latter.

I often switch colour schemes, and I have seen weird results because of the lack of `!` in links (and also lack of `gui` and `cterm` defaults), so I think the lack of `!` should be considered carefully when defining a highlight. If users really want to overwrite some link, they can define them (with `!`) in [scripts in their `after` directory](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10035/how-can-i-make-highlighting-commands-in-vimrc-take-effect-immediately-with-vim/10036#10036)